# How to insert DATE() in format DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am using the below `INSERT` command however the format is '***yyyy-mm-dd***'. How would I change this to display as ***dd/mm/yyyy***?

Also, How would I display the week end (Last Day of week)? Sunday of every week, no matter what day it was run on?

```
insert into resource values ('APPUSER', date(),'Admin','0')
```

Comment: I guess you meant `however the format is yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is this what you are looking for?*

```
Insert into resource values ('APPUSER', strftime('%d-%m-%Y','now'), 'Admin','0')
```

Also check this [Sqllite date format functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html explains like this, I haven't tried this. Just leave a comment if it not works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for that. Got it working. How would I change the date to sunday of each week?

Comment: I think this might be the answer, the plus one day is for New Zealand 'SELECT strftime('%d/%m/%Y','now','weekday 6', '+1 day')'

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):009:0> d = Date.today
=> #<Date: 2013-03-02 ((2456354j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):010:0> d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
=> "02/03/2013"
```